# Visual Studio c++ registering arrow keys experiencing an error with the debug file

Tags: c++, debugging, console-application, arrow-keys

I'm attempting to make the console recognise when I type arrow keys. After doing a bit of research I've found this code which is supposed to work, but when I went to test it I'm receiving this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error MSB3371 The file "Debug\Testing
>   .A4F95277.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" cannot be created. The file or
>   directory is corrupted and unreadable.    Testing Project
>   ideas F:\Visual Studio
>   2019\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets 329

I've tried restarting the program still nothing. I have absolutely no clue why I get this error - any suggestions?

```
 #include <conio.h>

 #include <iostream>

 using namespace std;

 #define KEY_UP 72

 #define KEY_DOWN 80

 #define KEY_LEFT 75

 #define KEY_RIGHT 77

 int main()

  {

    int c = 0;

    while (1)

    {

        c = 0;

        switch ((c = _getch())) {

        case KEY_UP:

            cout << endl << "Up" << endl;//key up

            break;

        case KEY_DOWN:

            cout << endl << "Down" << endl; // key down

            break;

        case KEY_LEFT:

            cout << endl << "Left" << endl; // key left

            break;

        case KEY_RIGHT:

            cout << endl << "Right" << endl; // key right

            break;

        default:

            cout << endl << "null" << endl; // not arrow

            break;

        }

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: This error message has absolutely nothing to do with your code. You have a corrupt project and/or VS installation. Create a different clean project and copy your the source files there. If the problem persists, wipe and reinstall VS.

Comment: Thankyou you where right, i attemted to delete it and it would not work so i restarted my computer somehow my entire drive got corrupted lol what a great day